# How can I use ajax to submit a comment to a site?

Tags: html, ajax

I know I have a really dumb question, and im sorry for the beginner stupidity...

But is there an easy way to have an open text box, where when the user hits submit a comment is saved to the database and the comment box shrinks to dissapear?

THere must be a dead simple tutorial out there, I just didn't find one!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery:

```
$('.SubmitButton').click(function() { 
    var text = $('.TextBox').slideUp().text();
    $('.Loading').fadeIn();
    $.post(url, { text: text}, function(response) {
        $('.Loading').fadeOut();
        //Do something
    });
});
```